# Is it possible to get all nested input fields for an input object using a GraphQL introspection query?

Tags: api, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to create a GraphQL introspection query that will retrieve all input fields for a given mutation input object at the top level and all nested fields.

The API I'm testing this with is the Shopify Admin GraphQL API.

For example from the following page of the documentation:

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2022-10/mutations/productcreate

The productCreate mutation uses a ProductInput object as the input for the mutation. I would like to basically get all the input fields drilling down through the objects to their nested values.

Essentially I would like the following from the same page of the documentation:

```
{
  "input": {
    "bodyHtml": "",
    "collectionsToJoin": [
      ""
    ],
    "collectionsToLeave": [
      ""
    ],
    "customProductType": "",
    "descriptionHtml": "",
    "giftCard": true,
    "giftCardTemplateSuffix": "",
    "handle": "",
    "id": "",
    "images": [
      {
        "altText": "",
        "id": "",
        "src": ""
      }
    ],
    "metafields": [
      {
        "description": "",
        "id": "",
        "key": "",
        "namespace": "",
        "type": "",
        "value": ""
      }
    ],
    "options": [
      ""
    ],
    "privateMetafields": [
      {
        "key": "",
        "namespace": "",
        "owner": "",
        "valueInput": {
          "value": "",
          "valueType": ""
        }
      }
    ],
    "productCategory": {
      "productTaxonomyNodeId": ""
    },
    "productPublications": [
      {
        "channelHandle": "",
        "channelId": "",
        "publicationId": "",
        "publishDate": ""
      }
    ],
    "productType": "",
    "publications": [
      {
        "channelHandle": "",
        "channelId": "",
        "publicationId": "",
        "publishDate": ""
      }
    ],
    "publishDate": "",
    "publishOn": "",
    "published": true,
    "publishedAt": "",
    "redirectNewHandle": true,
    "requiresSellingPlan": true,
    "seo": {
      "description": "",
      "title": ""
    },
    "standardizedProductType": {
      "productTaxonomyNodeId": ""
    },
    "status": "",
    "tags": [
      ""
    ],
    "templateSuffix": "",
    "title": "",
    "variants": [
      {
        "barcode": "",
        "compareAtPrice": "",
        "fulfillmentServiceId": "",
        "harmonizedSystemCode": "",
        "id": "",
        "imageId": "",
        "imageSrc": "",
        "inventoryItem": {
          "cost": "",
          "tracked": true
        },
        "inventoryManagement": "",
        "inventoryPolicy": "",
        "inventoryQuantities": [
          {
            "availableQuantity": 1,
            "locationId": ""
          }
        ],
        "mediaSrc": [
          ""
        ],
        "metafields": [
          {
            "description": "",
            "id": "",
            "key": "",
            "namespace": "",
            "type": "",
            "value": ""
          }
        ],
        "options": [
          ""
        ],
        "position": 1,
        "price": "",
        "privateMetafields": [
          {
            "key": "",
            "namespace": "",
            "owner": "",
            "valueInput": {
              "value": "",
              "valueType": ""
            }
          }
        ],
        "productId": "",
        "requiresShipping": true,
        "sku": "",
        "taxCode": "",
        "taxable": true,
        "title": "",
        "weight": 1.1,
        "weightUnit": ""
      }
    ],
    "vendor": ""
  },
  "media": [
    {
      "alt": "",
      "mediaContentType": "",
      "originalSource": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried the following introspection query:

```
query GetInputTypeDetails($inputTypeName: String!) {
  __type(name: $inputTypeName) {
    name
    kind
    inputFields {
      name
      type {
        ...TypeFields
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment TypeFields on __Type {
  kind
  name
  ofType {
    kind
    name
    inputFields {
      name
      type {
        ...NestedTypeFields
      }
    }
    ofType {
      kind
      name
      inputFields {
        name
        type {
          ...NestedTypeFields
        }
      }
      ofType {
        kind
        name
        inputFields {
          name
          type {
            ...NestedTypeFields
          }
        }
        ofType {
          kind
          name
          inputFields {
            name
            type {
              ...NestedTypeFields
            }
          }
        } ofType {
          kind
          name
          inputFields {
            name
            type {
              ...NestedTypeFields
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment NestedTypeFields on __Type {
  kind
  name
  ofType {
    kind
    name
    ofType {
      kind
      name
    }
  }
}
```

With ProductInput as the inputTypeName, however I can't seem to reach the nested object input fields.

Snippet of the variants portion:

```
{
                    "name": "variants",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "LIST",
                        "name": null,
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "NON_NULL",
                            "name": null,
                            "inputFields": null,
                            "ofType": {
                                "kind": "INPUT_OBJECT",
                                "name": "ProductVariantInput",
                                "inputFields": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "barcode",
                                        "type": {
                                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                                            "name": "String",
                                            "ofType": null
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "compareAtPrice",
                                        "type": {
                                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                                            "name": "Money",
                                            "ofType": null
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "harmonizedSystemCode",
                                        "type": {
                                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                                            "name": "String",
                                            "ofType": null
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "id",
                                        "type": {
                                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                                            "name": "ID",
                                            "ofType": null
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "imageId",
                                        "type": {
                                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                                            "name": "ID",
                                            "ofType": null
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "imageSrc",
                                        "type": {
                                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                                            "name": "String",
                                            "ofType": null
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "mediaSrc",
                                        "type": {
                                            "kind": "LIST",
                                            "name": null,
                                            "ofType": {
                                                "kind": "NON_NULL",
                                                "name": null,
                                                "ofType": {
                                                    "kind": "SCALAR",
                                                    "name": "String"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "inventoryPolicy",
                                        "type": {
                                            "kind": "ENUM",
                                            "name": "ProductVariantInventoryPolicy",
                                            "ofType": null
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "inventoryQuantities",
                                        "type": {
                                            "kind": "LIST",
                                            "name": null,
                                            "ofType": {
                                                "kind": "NON_NULL",
                                                "name": null,
                                                "ofType": {
                                                    "kind": "INPUT_OBJECT",
                                                    "name": "InventoryLevelInput"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "inventoryItem",
                                        "type": {
                                            "kind": "INPUT_OBJECT",
                                            "name": "InventoryItemInput",
                                            "ofType": null
                                        }
                                    }
Continued.............
```

The query doesn't return the deepest layer's fields, the inventoryQuantities object returns an InventoryLevelInput when it should be returning the fields as seen in the JSON object provided above of the InventoryLevelInput (availableQuantity and locationId). Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible? Is there a problem with my query or could this be a limitation of the API only allowing so many levels of nesting in a response?